# How to fill fields in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

need to know how to fill fields on web page and than click on button? Thanks.

Comment: Is this a Grails application?

Comment: this is application for submitting data to other sites-services. i just installed groovy on netbeans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of libraries that provide web client functionality. One such example is HTMLUnit, and there is a decent example called "Automating Form Submission" at PLEAC Groovy:

http://pleac.sourceforge.net/pleac_groovy/webautomation.html

Answer (score 0):

I use Watij (Web Application Testing in Java) pronounced asd wattage, inspired by Watir.
It has nice API such as finders (to find any element in DOM tree).

http://watij.com/